# UndefinedFunctionError phoenix elixir new project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

With a fresh install of Phoenix, I tried to trigger a new project, and when I try to run the server, I'm met with:

```
Unchecked dependencies for environment dev:
 * gettext (Hex package)
  the dependency is not available, run "mix deps.get"
 * phoenix_live_reload (Hex package)
  the dependency is not available, run "mix deps.get"
 * cowboy (Hex package)
 * List item
...
```

but when I run `mix deps.get` I get:

```
Running dependency resolution
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Access.Map.get_and_update!/3 (module Access.Map is not available)
    Access.Map.get_and_update!(%Mix.Dep{app: :cowboy, deps: [], extra: [], from: "/Users/victoriawagman/Dropbox/Hemsidor/digitalocean/hello_phoenix/mix.exs", manager: nil, opts: [hex: :cowboy, build: "/Users/victoriawagman/Dropbox/Hemsidor/digitalocean/hello_phoenix/_build/dev/lib/cowboy", dest: "/Users/victoriawagman/Dropbox/Hemsidor/digitalocean/hello_phoenix/deps/cowboy"], requirement: "~> 1.0", scm: Hex.SCM, status: {:unavailable, "/Users/victoriawagman/Dropbox/Hemsidor/digitalocean/hello_phoenix/deps/cowboy"}, top_level: true}, :deps, #Function<13.85268495/1 in Hex.Resolver.attach_dep_and_children/3>)
    (hex) lib/hex/resolver.ex:188: Hex.Resolver.attach_dep_and_children/3
    (hex) lib/hex/resolver.ex:148: Hex.Resolver.get_deps/5
    (hex) lib/hex/resolver.ex:107: Hex.Resolver.activate/6
    (hex) lib/hex/resolver.ex:31: Hex.Resolver.resolve/3
    (hex) lib/hex/remote_converger.ex:31: Hex.RemoteConverger.converge/2
    (mix) lib/mix/dep/converger.ex:92: Mix.Dep.Converger.all/4
    (mix) lib/mix/dep/converger.ex:47: Mix.Dep.Converger.converge/4
```

I'm at loss for what to search for to dig deeper into trying to figure out what I can do to understand what is wrong and fix it. Please assume that I have no clue, I'm learning.

Also, I don't know how to separately re-install just hex, so I'm looking for that now, if it is so that I also have a [corrupt install of hex](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1307).

Comment: what version of Elixir are you using?

Comment: What version of Phoenix and Elixir are you running? You can find your Elixir version by typing `iex --version` and you can see your phoenix version by looking for the phoenix.new task after running `mix help`

Comment: iex --version
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

and
Phoenix v1.1.1

Comment: Sweet! That the phoenix version is included in the mix phoenix.new :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems that my install of hex was corrupt.
running

```
mix local.hex
```

as per [Henrik](http://thepugautomatic.com/)'s suggestion solved this!
He'd a post by someone else indicating that [hex might be corrupt](http://qiita.com/K_ichi/items/230903d0868669d9deea).

Next up was a warning about missing module brunch, but that was solved by running npm install (as the output when triggering the server suggested).

Happy days!

Comment: Glad you fixed it! :D Hex probably got "corrupt" because you have updated your Elixir version and the old Hex, for the old Elixir versions, was still installed on your machine.