# elixir - phoenix:undefined function Hex.SCM.managers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

when runnig

```
mix phoenix.server
undefined function Hex.SCM.managers/1
```

is returning. Does anybody know which package should I install? 
Elixir is in version 1.2.3 and Erlang/OTP 18
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `mix local.hex` to install hex package manager. More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567624/undefinedfunctionerror-phoenix-elixir-new-project

Comment: mix local.hex - nothing changed, no error. I realized mix deps.get returns the same error.

Comment: Same problem for me after upgrading to 1.3.1,  Installing local hex didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Hex install is corrupted.
Try forcing the installation with `mix local.hex --force`.

Also you could try manually downloading and installing the latest version.

```
$ wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.hex.pm/installs/1.1.0/hex-0.11.5.ez
$ mix archive.install hex-0.11.5.ez
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `mix hex.info` to verify that your version of Hex is outdated. (E.g., `Hex v0.7.5`.)
2. Remove the directory `~/.mix` then run `mix local.hex --force`.
3. Run `mix hex.info` again; the version should be up to date.

Comment: Thanks! This was the only way I could fix Hex. For some reason even doing `mix local.hex --force` didn't work. Had to manually remove `~/.mix`